# How to search for a specific POS-tag while in nltk?

Tags: python, nltk

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import PunktSentenceTokenizer
#Other lines of code
question = ['Add a device under the name karthik']
responses = ['Added']

if user_text in question:
    token = word_tokenize(user_text)
    custom_sent_tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer([question])
    tokenized = custom_sent_tokenizer.tokenize(user_text)
    for i in tokenized[:5]:
        words = nltk.word_tokenize(i)
        tagged = nltk.pos_tag(words)
        print(tagged)
```

After the execution, i get the tokenized words with equivalent POS-tags. Now i need to know how to search for a particular POS-tag, so that i can perform some filtering in the text !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple list comp:

```
>>> sentence = "A screaming comes across the sky."
>>> tokenized = word_tokenize(sentence)
>>> tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized)
>>> [_ for x in tagged if _[1] == 'NN']
[('screaming', 'NN'), ('sky', 'NN')]
```

Or you can use [filtering](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#filter):

```
>>> sentence = "I am seated in an office, surrounded by heads and bodies."
>>> tokenized = word_tokenize(sentence)
>>> tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized)
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x[1] == 'NNS', tagged))
[('heads', 'NNS'), ('bodies', 'NNS')]
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: The first method didn't work for me but the second one did.